# HTML alignment and javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a slider in HTML and I'm having two issues.

1. I'm trying to get the following group of elements to show up horizontally in a line `[checkbox][color-box][slider][slider-value]`. But for some reason the color box is causing the line to wrap. The code I have for this is:

```css
.color-box {
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  margin:5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="type-controls">
  <input type="checkbox" >
  <div class="color-box"</div>  
  <input type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 id=fader step=1 oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
  <output for=fader id=volume>50</output>    
</div>
```

2. I can't get the value of the slider to update as I'm moving the slider. (Would this even work on a per control basis?)

```js
function outputUpdate(vol) { 
  document.querySelector('#volume').value = vol;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdubbs/c1g9hmz4/2/

Comment: First, you're missing a `>` in `<div class="color-box"</div>`. Then, by default, a `div` is a block element, which means it takes its own line, unless you make it `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` (or `float: left`, which is not what you want here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Line Wrap Issue**
Change `<div class="color-box"></div>` to `<span class="color-box"></span>`. (In your original code, you forgot a closing `>`). A `div` is a [block element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), and will always take up a whole line, unless you specify otherwise with [`display: inline-block;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values)

In this case, because the `color-box` is empty, you need to add `display: inline-block` regardless, otherwise it will not take up space, and `width` will be `1`.

**Slider Issue**
As for the function, it looks like you're calling the function before it is defined. Make sure the `script` appears before the HTML. (For JSFiddle, set `No wrap - in <body>` on the left hand side)

For future reference, you should check the console / debugger. In this case it shows

> ReferenceError: outputUpdate is not defined

which tells us the issue.

**Nitpicks**
Change `...id=volume...` to `...id="volume"...` and `...id=fader...` to `...id="fader" ...`. Also, while it will still work as you have it, it's considered invalid HTML if you have more than one `id` of the same name. Change `id` to `class` for `volume` and `fader`.

**One more issue**
Now that you've changed `id` to `class`, your script won't work. So now remove the `oninput="outputUpdate(value)"` and replace your script with:

```
$('.fader').on('input', function() {

    var vol = $(this).val();
    $(this).next('.volume').val(vol);

});
```

What this does is [bind the `input event`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to the function. What this means is, whenever you click on a `slider`, jQuery will trigger the code in the function block on a per control basis as you wanted.  If you're new to jQuery, [`$(this)`](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified) references the `slider` you clicked on (so we can differentiate between the 3 sliders you have).

The [`.next('.volume')`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will select the next `volume` class (otherwise your code will just update the first volume output, regardless of slider used) and then apply the value change.

**Working example**
[Here's your JSFiddle with the changes](http://jsfiddle.net/c1g9hmz4/7/) added for you.

Comment: there is an error in the html. need to add missing `>` on the opening tag

Comment: 1) So how would I define the box size when it's in a span?

Comment: @cwodwrth Whether it's a span or a div, you'll need `display: inline-block` for it to both 1) have a size and  2) display inline.

Comment: @cdubbs, I've updated the answer and code to fully work. Let me know if it helps and if I should clarify anything

Answer (score 1):

I would add css to format the display to be horizontal (I also changed the `color-box` to be a span.

```
.group-controls input,span,output{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

You should also change `id=fader` to `class=fader` since ids should be unique, here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqy2rojc/2/)

Or here is an example:

```js
$('.color-box').colpick({
    colorScheme: 'dark',
    layout: 'rgbhex',
    color: 'ff8800',
    onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
      $(el).css('background-color', '#' + hex);
      $(el).colpickHide();
    }
  })
  .css('background-color', '#ff8800');

function outputUpdate(vol) {
  document.querySelector('#volume').value = vol;
}
```

```css
.color-box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.group-controls input,
span,
output {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://web.stakinc.com/test/css/colpick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://web.stakinc.com/test/js/colpick.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 1:</legend>

    <div class="group-controls">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="color-box"></span> 
      <input type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 class='fader' step=1 oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
      <output for=fader id=volume>50</output>
    </div>
    <div class="group-controls">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="color-box"></span> 
      <input type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 class='fader' step=1 oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
      <output for=fader id=volume>50</output>
    </div>

    <div class="group-controls">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="color-box"></span> 
      <input type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 class='fader' step=1 oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
      <output for=fader id=volume>50</output>
    </div>





  </fieldset>
</form>
```